# If 10 coins were flipped

Tags: probability

If 10 coins were flipped, what would be the probability of 9 of them landing on heads? Would it be 1/512 or would the probability be different considering that 1 coin failed at landing on heads?
Thank you

Comment: $\frac{1}{512}=\frac{1}{2^9}$ is the probability that in nine flips, all nine are heads, or equivalently that in ten flips, the first nine are heads and the tenth is either.

Answer (score 1):

There are $2^{10}$ (equally probable) outcomes of $10$ coin flips. There are $10$ different possible outcomes where exactly 9 coins land on heads: $HHHHHHHHHT$, $HHHHHHHHTH$, ... $THHHHHHHHH$. So the probability is $\frac{10}{2^{10}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Define a coin ending up being heads a success, with probability $p$. Then, by the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), we have

$$\binom{10}{9}p^{9}(1-p)^{1}.$$

If the coin is fair, $p=\frac{1}{2}$ and the probability becomes 
$$\binom{10}{9}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{10}=10\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{10}\approx 1\%.$$

Comment: So would that make a 1/102.4 chance then?

Comment: @user329957 Yes!